# Sort on first entry of ArrayList in ArrayList

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I have an ArrayList that consists of an ArrayList that constists of Strings: `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>`. How can I sort on the first entry of he inner ArrayList? For example I would like this:

```
a = [['1','apple'],['3','pear'],['2','banana'],['1',orange']]
```

to become:

```
a_sorted = [['1','apple'],['1','orange'],['2','banana'],['3','pear']]
```

The order of duplicate first entries (like `apple` and `orange`) do not matter. I've tried using `Collections.sort(a,new ColumnComparator())` but it will not accept ArrayLists. This is the class I used:

```
public class ColumnComparator implements Comparator<ArrayList<String>>{
    public int compare(ArrayList<String> ar1, ArrayList<String> ar2){
        return ar1.get(0).compareTo(ar2.get(0));
    }
}
```

Comment: `Collections.sort` ought to accept ArrayLists. Were you passing in an ArrayList, or an ArrayList<String>?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Sort, sorts on the natural order of the elements. There is no natural order on these subarrays.

Comment: "I have an ArrayList that consists of an ArrayList that consists of Strings" You have the wrong data structure at hand if you ask me. Sounds like you want a Multimap. Have a look at [Guava Multimaps](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html)

Comment: @WilQu the error is: `The method sort(List<T>, Comparator<? super T>) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>, ColumnComparator)`

Comment: @Zim-ZamO'Pootertoot I pass in an ArrayList. The outer one.

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd It seems to me that the natural order of '3' and '1' is '1','3'. To my knowledge Java knows about this, just like it knows about Lexicographical ordering. At least that's what I expect.

Comment: @Tim yes, String implements `Comparable<String>`, which is called natural order (when X implements `Compareable<X>`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of storing an Array of an Array, why don't you create a custom Class that implements [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html). eg.

```
class Fruit implements Comparable<Fruit> {
protected int number;
protected String name;

public Fruits(int number, String name) {
    this.number = number;
    this.name = name;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Fruit f) {
    return number < f.number;
    // or depending on if ascending or descending order wanted
    // return number > f.number 
}
}
```

Then to sort just run `Collections.sort(a)`. This way is flexible and easily extended.

Comment: Eventually I went with this idea because it is indeed very easy extendable. And it also gave me ideas to solve other problems.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a **`Map <String, ArrayList<String>>`** with first entry of the ArrayLists as key and the ArrayList itself as value. Then sort the Map (use [Sorted Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html) or a [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) to sort on the Map keys) on keys and you will get what you want.

Comment: I have though about this but the Strings on which have to be sorted, as you might see, are not unique (even though the combination of rest of the entries are). Wouldn't that mess up the Map?

Comment: You are correct. In that case use a Map<String, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>, which will solve the problem of non-unique first entries. Before inserting key-value pairs into the map, check if the value exists, and if it does.. just add the ArrayList to the List of ArrayLists already stored in the map.

Answer (score 0):

Why cant you use a this `ArrayList<Map<String,String>>` instead of `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>`. You can easily sort the Map on the key by using TreeMap. 
Note: This will only work if you have only two entries in your inner arraylist.

Comment: This was merely an example, my inner ArrayList is in fact much larger.

Comment: Still what you can do is replace your inner ArrayList with Map<String,List<String>>. Here the first element of the inner Arraylist can be used as key of the map and rest as values(List<String>). Using TreeMap you will be able to easily sort the elements on first value.

Comment: Doesn't that create to much overhead? Since I will be creating a LOT of Maps that way.

Comment: Not really. you will just create a single map with multiple List's within it. But the key point to note is that you dont have to iterate or compare the arraylist value(first value) by yourself to keep them sorted. It will be easily handled by the map in an efficient manner.

Answer (score 0):

If you *really* want to do it that way, you can try this:

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class ColumnComparable implements Comparator<ArrayList<String>>{

    @Override
    public int compare(ArrayList<String> o1, ArrayList<String> o2) {
        return (Integer.parseInt(o1.get(0)) > Integer.parseInt(o2.get(0)) ? -1 : (Integer.parseInt(o1.get(0)) == Integer.parseInt(o2.get(0)) ? 0 : 1));
    }
}
```

The code was found [here](http://www.vogella.com/blog/2009/08/04/collections-sort-java/).